# A graph on which a free group acts freely is a tree?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory

Let $F$ a free group acting freely on a graph $X$. Does this imply that $X$ is a tree?

If $F=\mathbb Z$, the answer is no. For example $\mathbb Z$ acts on $\mathbb Z^2$ by translations.

But  what about the other free groups?

As $F_2$ contains $F_k$ as a subgroup $\forall k$, it would suffice to show that the claim is also falso for $F=F_2$.

However I could not think of any graph which is not a tree on which $F_2$ acts freely. In particular, letting one generetor ($b$) act trivially does not give a free action, because then $1\neq aba^-1$ acts as the identity.

Comment: Copying the example of $F = {\mathbb Z}$, $F_2$ acts freely on the Cayley graph of $F_2 \times H$ for any group $H$.

Comment: I think I got it. If I understood it correctly, it works for any grpah of the form $X \times A$ wtih $A$ an arbitrary graph and $X$ the Cayley graph of $F_2$